# Android Dynamically changing one child Layout height

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, height

I wanted to make a layout which has three children layout.

the bottom layout must visible to bottom

screen size is enough:
the center layout need Dynamically change to wrap_content and we need the bottom layout is under the center layout (not top of the parent).

screen size is not enough:
fix size of center layout will fixed and it is a scrollview, it's height is dependency on the reminding width(if screen size is not enough)

I think a lot of ideas but i don't know how can do using xml. It can be only calculate in runtime?

this is the intend image:
[image]

Comment: comment; top and bottom layout is fixed size

Comment: what have  you tried? post it here.

Comment: I can't post here because of some reason. but i do it in the constraintlayout and the bottom layout constraint center layout together and bottom parent. But it is not my excepting because when the screen size is enough. the bottom layout will center between center layout and bottom parent

Comment: show your xml code

Comment: can't post. or maybe we just discuss and brainstorm here together.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `wrap_content` in xml

OR

To change programatically you can use following code

`Your_Layout.getLayoutParams().height = 100;`

Comment: using wrap_content is wrong because the center layout maybe bigger than screen height and the bottom layout cannot see.

Comment: the second way can do it if I calculate. thanks for brainstorming. but i wanted someone who knows using xml can doing this?

Comment: Why are you not posting your xml codes in rough ? If you post your code we can help you easiily.